# regarding "Uncle Johnny" problem_ on CodeChef

Tags: java, arrays, string, int, binary-search

There is a practice problem `Uncle Johny` on `www.codechef.com`

Being a lengthy one, I am providing the link to that.

https://www.codechef.com/problems/JOHNY/

I am having two solutions to that problem (code 1 and code 2)

#### Code 1

```
class UncleJohny
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(System.in));
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(System.out);

        int test_case = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        while(test_case-- > 0)
        {
            int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

            int i = 0;

            String a[] = br.readLine().split(" ");   //Mind this line

            int k = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

            String temp = a[k - 1];

            Arrays.sort(a);

            pw.println(Arrays.binarySearch(a, temp) + 1);
        }

        pw.flush();
    }
}
```

#### Code 2

```
class UncleJohny
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(System.out);

        int test_case = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        while(test_case-- > 0)
        {
            int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

            int a[] = new int[n];

            int i = 0;

            for(String str: br.readLine().split(" "))
            {
                a[i++] = Integer.parseInt(str);     //Mind this line
            }

            int k = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

            int temp = a[k - 1];

            Arrays.sort(a);

            pw.println(Arrays.binarySearch(a, temp) + 1);
        }

        pw.flush();
    }
}
```

*Basic task in the above codes is to find the index of value of `temp` in the input array `a` after sorting*

According to me, there won't be any difference in the output of both the codes. (Correct me if I am wrong)

CodeChef is accepting `Code 2`, but saying **Wrong Answer** for `Code 1`

#### What my query exactly is ?

Despite of being same, why `code 2` is accepted whereas `code 1` is not?

Why I need to store the input values in `int` array (As shown in code 2) rather than storing them into `String` array (As shown in code 1), in order to get my answer accepted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sort order for integers is different from that for strings. E.g. "1" < "10" < "2" ...